# how long music or how much music

Tags: word-choice

> **Ask:** ______ music do you listen to every day?
>
> **Answer:** Less than an hour.
>
> A. How much
>     B. How long

I  choose A.

If I use "how long", I would say

> How long do you listen to music every day?

or

> How long of music do you listen to every day?

Could you tell me if I am right or wrong? And please tell me which way you usually say in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct. The question is "How **much** music do you listen to every day." Or it could be "How long do you listen to music every day." "How long of music" is not correct.

If I were to ask the question, I'd ask "How much music do you listen to **each** day." Using *every* in the question implies that the answer you receive will be the same for all days. With *each* I would be more comfortable telling you that I listen for a few hours on the weekends, and much less on weekdays.

Comment: How to say "How long this song"? The answer is supposed to be like "3 minutes" or "5 minutes".

Comment: "How long **is** this song?"